# Where are database specific settings stored?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres documentation says `ALTER SYSTEM` writes the given parameter values to the `postgresql.auto.conf file`, which is read in addition to `postgresql.conf`.

I am curious about where the `alter database set configuration parameter` details are stored.

Comment: No. Role and database configurations are stored in [pg_db_role_setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-db-role-setting.html) which is shared across all databases of a cluster.

Answer (score 13):

Database-level settings are not stored in any configuration file, but the `pg_db_role_setting` catalog, the only question is how to get them out there.

As often in similar cases, `psql` can be of tremendous help here.  The key is `\set ECHO_HIDDEN on`, which then shows the queries behind the different [meta-commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS).

In one of my sandbox DBs I see the following:

```
test=# \drds
                       List of settings
    Role     │ Database │              Settings               
─────────────┼──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────
 alice       │          │ log_statement=none                 ↵
             │          │ work_mem=12MB
 bob         │          │ log_statement=all                  ↵
             │          │ work_mem=64MB
 luser       │          │ log_statement=all
 tom         │          │ log_statement=all
             │ test     │ search_path=test, public
             │ wacky    │ default_transaction_read_only=true
```

We are interested in the rows where there is no user specified - these are exactly the settings you were asking about.  With `ECHO_HIDDEN` on, you also get the following query (the formatting is mine):

```
SELECT rolname AS "Role", 
       datname AS "Database",
       pg_catalog.array_to_string(setconfig, E'\n') AS "Settings"
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting s
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_database d ON d.oid = setdatabase
  LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_roles r ON r.oid = setrole
 ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

One can simplify this to get only the DB-specific settings:

```
SELECT datname AS database,
pg_catalog.array_to_string(setconfig, E'\n') AS settings
FROM pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting s
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_database d ON d.oid = setdatabase ORDER BY 1, 2;

 database │              settings               
──────────┼─────────────────────────────────────
 test     │ search_path=test, public
 wacky    │ default_transaction_read_only=true
```